# How to share .net console application with client for getting his feedback

Tags: .net, console-application

I am working on writing a Console Application in .NET which basically generates Excel  reports. Now this Console Application refers to 2 external Libraries

- Domain Layer (Which is a dll abstracting the business logic)
- Third party dll which helps generating excel files

Now there are many configuration items which I have set in the app.config (Including connectionstring, FolderPath to generate reports, MSMQ name)

My question is How do I send this Console Application to my client so that he can run it and see how is it behaving in his Envirnment

Comment: zip it all up and email it? put it in dropbox to share?

Comment: Well what's wrong with sending him the DLLs and the executable, with the config file?

Comment: @JonSkeet So If I send him the .exe and all required dll's and the config file. Will that do? The problem I am seeing is, If I run the exe from bin/Release folder, everythign's works well but If I copy the exe + dlls + app.config and place it in another folder , I get an exception on executing the exe -- says the configuration file doesn't contain appsetting element with the key 'MSMQName' (I have set it in app.config though)

Comment: are you also copying the `.exe.config`?

Comment: @DLeh No , I am not. I just tried adding that as well and it did the trick. Wasn't sure if we had to add this file also. So basically configuration gets stored here? But what if the client needs to change some configuration? He can't do it? Can you put this in an answer so that I can mark it as an answer also

Comment: the `.exe.config` file will be used when running instead of the `app.config`. copy that over, it should work.

Comment: generally, anything in the output directory (`bin/Release`) was deemed necessary to run the application from the compiler, so copy all of it anywhere you need it to run.

Comment: @DLeh Is it possible for my client to change the configuration? If yes, how can they do so?

Comment: have them edit the `exe.config` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @DLeh, I zipped everything in the bin/Release folder and sent it to the client and he was able to run the application.